# How to loop over the items of multiple list simultaneously based on the indices

Tags: python

I will like to have your ideas about solving this looping problem on multiple lists. I have multiple lists of different lengths like:
`['dog','cat'], [5,45,8,9], ['yellow','blue','black']`.

I want to be be able to do something like access the elements of these lists like this:

```
1. ['dog', 5, 'yellow']
2. ['dog', 5, 'blue']
3. ['dog', 5, 'black']
4. ['dog', 45, 'yellow']
5. ['dog', 45, 'blue']
6. ['dog', 45, 'black']
7. ['dog', 8, 'yellow']
8. ['dog', 8, 'blue']
9. ['dog', 8, 'black']
10. ['dog', 9, 'yellow']
11. ['dog', 9, 'blue']
12. ['dog', 9, 'black']
13. ['cat', 5, 'yellow']
14. ['cat', 5, 'blue']
15. ['cat', 5, 'black']
16. ['cat', 45, 'yellow']
17. ['cat', 45, 'blue']
18. ['cat', 45, 'black']
19. ['cat', 8, 'yellow']
20. ['cat', 8, 'blue']
21. ['cat', 8, 'black']
22. ['cat', 9, 'yellow']
23. ['cat', 9, 'blue']
24. ['cat', 9, 'black']
```

Thanks. I have to repost it because the formatting makes it clumsy and a little bit unreadable

Answer (score 7):

You're looking for `itertools.product`:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> animal = ['dog','cat']
>>> number = [5,45,8,9]
>>> color = ['yellow','blue','black']
for i,p in enumerate(product(animal, number, color),1):
    print "{}. {}".format(i,str(list(p)))
...     
1. ['dog', 5, 'yellow']
2. ['dog', 5, 'blue']
3. ['dog', 5, 'black']
4. ['dog', 45, 'yellow']
5. ['dog', 45, 'blue']
6. ['dog', 45, 'black']
7. ['dog', 8, 'yellow']
8. ['dog', 8, 'blue']
9. ['dog', 8, 'black']
10. ['dog', 9, 'yellow']
11. ['dog', 9, 'blue']
12. ['dog', 9, 'black']
13. ['cat', 5, 'yellow']
14. ['cat', 5, 'blue']
15. ['cat', 5, 'black']
16. ['cat', 45, 'yellow']
17. ['cat', 45, 'blue']
18. ['cat', 45, 'black']
19. ['cat', 8, 'yellow']
20. ['cat', 8, 'blue']
21. ['cat', 8, 'black']
22. ['cat', 9, 'yellow']
23. ['cat', 9, 'blue']
24. ['cat', 9, 'black']
```

Comment: Thanks Ashwini! But in have one more question. Is this applicable to list of lists. For instance, let's say dog, 5, yellow each are lists like this: [2,4,8], [7,0,3,9,12],[66,9,23]. And do i have to put the lists as list of lists before doing it the way you did. Is there a way i can do that with lists separate? Thank you

Comment: @user2553377 yes, just pass the lists to `product` like this : `product(list1, list2, list3)`

Comment: @ Ashwini. Like you did before as:for i,p in enumerate(product(*lis),1) or I need to pass as product first. Soory for the troubles. Can you please write out an example.

Comment: @user2553377 I've updated my solution, is that what you wanted?

Comment: @user2553377 For a list of lists like : `lis = [['dog', 'cat'], [5, 45, 8, 9], ['yellow', 'blue', 'black']]`, use `product(*lis)`.
`

Comment: i found out that your first solution was more useful to my program but the result of this:>>> for i,p in enumerate(product(*lis),1) is a tuple. How can I make it a list directly

Comment: @user2553377 both itertools.product and enumerate return a tuple, so you need to use list() to convert that tuple to a list.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly more "pedestrian" way to loop over the different lists and make a combined list:

```
animal = ['dog','cat']
number = [5,45,8,9]
color = ['yellow','blue','black']
num = 0
combined = []

for a in animal:
  for n in number:
    for c in color:
      print a, n, c
      combined.append([a, n, c])

print combined
```

Saving this exact code in a file `animal.py`, and running it from the command line with `python animal.py` results in the following output:

```
dog 5 yellow
dog 5 blue
dog 5 black
dog 45 yellow
dog 45 blue
dog 45 black
dog 8 yellow
dog 8 blue
dog 8 black
dog 9 yellow
dog 9 blue
dog 9 black
cat 5 yellow
cat 5 blue
cat 5 black
cat 45 yellow
cat 45 blue
cat 45 black
cat 8 yellow
cat 8 blue
cat 8 black
cat 9 yellow
cat 9 blue
cat 9 black
[['dog', 5, 'yellow'], ['dog', 5, 'blue'], ['dog', 5, 'black'], ['dog', 45, 'yellow'], ['dog', 45, 'blue'], ['dog', 45, 'black'], ['dog', 8, 'yellow'], ['dog', 8, 'blue'], ['dog', 8, 'black'], ['dog', 9, 'yellow'], ['dog', 9, 'blue'], ['dog', 9, 'black'], ['cat', 5, 'yellow'], ['cat', 5, 'blue'], ['cat', 5, 'black'], ['cat', 45, 'yellow'], ['cat', 45, 'blue'], ['cat', 45, 'black'], ['cat', 8, 'yellow'], ['cat', 8, 'blue'], ['cat', 8, 'black'], ['cat', 9, 'yellow'], ['cat', 9, 'blue'], ['cat', 9, 'black']]
```

If you want a specific element, you can now do (for example)

```
print "element 3 is ", combined[3]
```

This will return

```
element 3 is  ['dog', 45, 'yellow']
```

Comment: @user2553377: How is it not working?  (It worked for me, btw.)

Comment: @user2553377 - sorry you are having trouble. I clarified my answer a bit more. Please let me know what is happening for you if it's not what I am showing.

Comment: Thanks my response was based on the first solution you provided. thanks it worked!

Comment: Sorry Floris, my response was based on the first solution you posted. It worked!